# Redirecting output in sub-functions

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to write a wrapper that will execute the function that the cursor is over and send its output to a log file. Here is what I have so far:

```
nnoremap <expr> GG ExecuteCurrentFunction()
func ExecuteCurrentFunction ()
    " get the current word under the cursor and execute if a function
    " redirecting output to a log file
    redir >> vim.log
    let name_of_function = expand("<cword>")
    let call_string = printf(':call %s()', name_of_function)
    echom call_string
    call execute(call_string)
    redir END
endfunc
```

It works great, however it doesn't seem to be redirecting any of the `echom` statements in the called function. For example, if the function I execute is:

```
func NewFunction ()
    echom "Calling inner function"
endfunc
```

It will only print the following to my log file:

```
:call NewFunction()
```

And it won't print `Calling inner function`. Why is this so, and how could I change this to effectively create a wrapper function as I'm trying to above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `execute()` has `silent` modifier by default, so normal output doesn't appear on the screen. It must be invoked as `execute(cmd, '')` to allow "echoing".
2. `execute()` is a sort of `:redir` by itself (essentially it captures the output into a variable and returns it to the caller), and you cannot do two redirections at a time. It should become clear from reading `:h :redir` and `:h execute()` until the end.

You can either directly save output of `execute()` with `writefile()`, or use `:execute` command instead.

Comment: `s/operator/command`